# Azure Function reaching timeout without doing anything

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have an Azure Function app in Node.js with a couple of Queue-triggered functions.

These were working great, until I saw a couple of timeouts in my function logs.
From that point, none of my triggered functions are actually doing anything. They just keep timing out even **before executing the first line of code**, which is a `context.log()`-statement to show the execution time.

[image: LogOutput]

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: have you tried recycling instance?

Comment: I tried restarting my App Service but that doesn't seem to help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your functions storage account in the azure portal, you'll likely see very high activity for files monitoring.

This is likely due to the interaction between Azure Files and requiring a large `node_modules` tree. Once the modules have been required once, functions will execute quickly because modules are cached, but these timeouts can throw the function app into a timeout -> restart loop.

There's a lot of discussion on this, along with one possible improvement (using webpack on server side modules) [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/298#issuecomment-273851188).

Other possibilities:

- decrease number of node modules if possible
- move to dedicated instead of consumption plan (it runs on a different file system which has better performance)
- use C# or F#, which don't suffer from these limitations

Comment: "Once the modules have been required once, functions will execute quickly because modules are cached", this problem started occuring at random, so I would think my modules should have been cached already? I do see my storage account costing me quite some money , would that have something to do with the `node_modules` as well? Are they constantly reloading my modules?

Comment: Yes. If a timeout is hit the azure functions host will restart, because it assumes there's an error. After a host restart, the modules must be reloaded (this can occur after a function code change, function app restart, etc). The caching is done by the node process itself in the require call (and a restart kills that process).

Comment: I see... Thanks for the insights! Is it easy to transfer my functions to a dedicated plan?

Comment: @Schaemelhout - please don't bury additional questions in comments (which encourages discussion in comments, which goes against the grain of StackOverflow's guidelines). Best to post a new question, if it's not clearly documented.